# How to iterate through multiple lines of input like a matrix, etc.?

Tags: javascript

I recently started HackerRank and throughout the problems, I've noticed that they often use multiple lines for the input. For example, for the Day 6: Let's Review challenge, the sample input is

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

which is referred to as a string. I want to know if there is a way to iterate by line instead of individual character. This format throws me off on a lot of the exercises, and I want to know if there is a way to make this easier.

Comment: Have you made any effort yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split()` the string by `\n`

```js
let str = `2
Hacker
Rank`
str = str.split('\n');
str.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x);
})
```

Comment: Does the \n make it split at the line?

Comment: @achromaticaries Yes

Comment: Can I use the same thing for an array?

Comment: @achromaticaries Please give an example. You mean array of strings?

Comment: Like if I have a matrix or an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use `` to write multiple lines string in Javascript